# Как выполнить такой LINQ запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Есть текстовый файл, в который записываются координаты точек на плоскости. По сути это просто два числа, записанных через пробел. Файл, может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
1 1
0 0
2 2
```

То есть, в каждой строке находится пара чисел, записанных через пробел(Первое число - координата Х, второе - Y).
Нужно при помощи LINQ считать строки, преобразовать в числа и сформировать список анонимных объектов, хранящих координаты каждой точки(поля Х и Y).
Как считать строки понятно, но вот как действовать дальше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так

```
var coords = File.ReadLines(".путь к файлу..")
        .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
        .Select(line => new { x = int.Parse(line[0]), y = int.Parse(line[1]) })
        .ToList();
```